# Magento 2: How To Setup Multi Website with Subdomain

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multi-website

I want to setup multiwebsite in Magento 2.
I want to setup multiwebsite in that way, So another website open like this URL `demo.mydomain.com`.

Hope you all can understand.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Taken from the Magento Dev documentation.

Comment: I checked this but it is not important for me. Can you please check my question again.